# JS adding padding top based on viewpoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, view

Is it possible to add the padding top to an element based on the viewpoint/screen size?

E.g you have a large image banner and you want that to be the first thing you see when you load the page, none of the content below because that has been pushed down via padding added via the viewpoint js, so you then scroll down to that.

So a responsive image then your content, but the image always fills the screen first regardless of screen size?

You then scroll the content up over the banner image, hence the need for dynamic padding based on screen size?

Comment: Yes it is possible ^^ look into these jquery functions
$(document).height(); and http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to add a padding/margin on the top of the page to push its main content down to the height of the screen.

Here is a quick JS i wrote with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Put this code inside the `<head>` tags after the include tag for jQuery itself.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".contentClass").css('padding-top', $(window).height());
});
```

You can add the jQuery library with this tag in the `<head>` tags of the html document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what i mean, i’ll give it a go!

Comment: This works, but any way of having it in percentages rather than pixels? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know of any tricks at hand. But i think the best bet is using JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that your image will *push* the content as soon as possible so people visiting the website won't see the content below, I'd suggest plain javascript executed NOT after the whole page load but placed just under the image and executed immediately after the image is loaded:

```
<img id="banner" src="my-image.jpg">
<script>
    var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
    banner.onload = function() {
        banner.style.marginTop = (window.innerHeight - banner.offsetHeight) + 'px';
    };
</script>
```

Yet, better approach is to load image into DOM by javascript

```
<div id="banner"></div>
<script>
    var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
    var img = new Image();

    banner.appendChild(img);
    img.onload = function() {
        banner.style.marginTop = (window.innerHeight - banner.offsetHeight) + 'px';
    };
    img.src = 'my-image.jpg';
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, will this work if the image is actually a background image of an element rather than a physical img?

Comment: It won't at all. If you want to use image as a `background` you can't fetch its dimensions. You would have to simply know them.